# My datalab VM instance always throw 'Not Found' error to me

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bD6b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmY8a.png)

I created a datalab VM through the console shell, but the file related to the created VM does not exist in the bucket, and even if I try to add a notebook through datalab, and upload a file,'Not Found' error occurs and no action is taken not.

What is the problem?

p.s: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/building-chatbot-agent-dialogflow
I created a VM using this document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/2169#issuecomment-663944128), there seems to be a known issue with Datalab and Cloud Shell.

Alternatively, you can access your Dataflow instance from somewhere other than the Cloud Shell, for example, from a local Linux machine. To do this, you can perform the following procedure (please consider that the Datalab instance must be turned on):

1. SSH Keys

   1.1) Create a pair of keys for SSH, you can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) to do it

   1.2) Locate your [SSH_KEY.pub key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#locatesshkeys) created in the previous step and add it to the [public SSH key metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide)
2. [Create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall#creating_a_firewall_ingress_rule) in the network: ‘datalab-network’ with these settings:

- Network: datalab-network
- Direction of traffic: Ingress
- Action on match: Allow
- Targets: All instances in the network
- Source: IP ranges
- Source IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
- Second source filter: None
- Protocols and ports:

  - Specified protocols and ports

    - tcp: 22

3. Connect to the Datalab instance

   3.1) [Locate the External IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/view-ip-address#viewing_ip_addresses) of your Datalab instance. This IP will be used in the next step as: <EXT_IP_INSTANCE>

   3.2) Using a terminal, create a tunnel to the Datalab instance with the following command: ‘ssh -L 8080: localhost: 8080 <EXT_IP_INSTANCE>’

   3.3) Open Google Chrome and type ‘localhost: 8080’ in the search bar. You should see the Datalab interface.